# Playing you tube api from you tube channel not playing in landscape mode

Tags: android, youtube-api, landscape

Hi all I am now integrating youtube API in my app where I have to parse the list of video id's from API then I have to show the videos in a list view when we click on it the video has to be played **Until this works fine**

There after when the user selects the full-screen mode that is landscape mode I get some errors

```
public final class VideoGallery extends Fragment implements OnFullscreenListener {

    public static Context context;
    public static final int ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS = 300;
    public static final int LANDSCAPE_VIDEO_PADDING_DP = 5;
    public final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;
    public static VideoListFragment listFragment;
    public static VideoFragment videoFragment;
    View videoBox;
    View view;
    View closeButton;
    boolean isFullscreen;
    public static YouTubePlayer.OnFullscreenListener onFullscreenListener;
    static boolean back = false;
    FrameLayout relativeLayout;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        context = getContext();
        onFullscreenListener = this;
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        relativeLayout = new FrameLayout(getActivity());
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_demo, relativeLayout, true);
        MainActivity.headerText.setText("Video Gallery");
        listFragment = (VideoGallery.VideoListFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.list_fragment);
        videoFragment = (VideoGallery.VideoFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);

        videoBox = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.video_box);
        closeButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
        closeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listFragment.getListView().clearChoices();
                listFragment.getListView().requestLayout();
                videoFragment.pause();
                ViewPropertyAnimator animator = videoBox.animate()
                        .translationYBy(videoBox.getHeight())
                        .setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
                runOnAnimationEnd(animator, new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        videoBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        layout();

        checkYouTubeApi();

        return relativeLayout;
    }

    private void checkYouTubeApi() {
        YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason =
                YouTubeApiServiceUtil.isYouTubeApiServiceAvailable(context);
        if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
            errorReason.getErrorDialog(getActivity(), RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
        } else if (errorReason != YouTubeInitializationResult.SUCCESS) {
            String errorMessage =
                    String.format(getString(R.string.error_player), errorReason.toString());
            Toast.makeText(context, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
            // Recreate the activity if user performed a recovery action
            getActivity().recreate();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        layout();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFullscreen(boolean isFullscreen) {
        this.isFullscreen = isFullscreen;
        layout();
    }

    private void layout() {
        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        listFragment.getView().setVisibility(isFullscreen ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
        listFragment.setLabelVisibility(isPortrait);
        closeButton.setVisibility(isPortrait ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        if (isFullscreen) {
            videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
            setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
            setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);
        } else if (isPortrait) {
            setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT);
            setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT);
            setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, MATCH_PARENT, WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.BOTTOM);
        } else {
            videoBox.setTranslationY(0); // Reset any translation that was applied in portrait.
            int screenWidth = dpToPx(getResources().getConfiguration().screenWidthDp);
            setLayoutSize(listFragment.getView(), screenWidth / 4, MATCH_PARENT);
            int videoWidth = screenWidth - screenWidth / 4;
            setLayoutSize(videoFragment.getView(), videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT);
            setLayoutSizeAndGravity(videoBox, videoWidth, WRAP_CONTENT,
                    Gravity.RIGHT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        }


    }

    @TargetApi(16)
    private void runOnAnimationEnd(ViewPropertyAnimator animator, final Runnable runnable) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
            animator.withEndAction(runnable);
        } else {
            animator.setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    runnable.run();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public static final class VideoListFragment extends ListFragment {

        private static List<VideoEntry> VIDEO_LIST;
        private PageAdapter adapter;
        private View videoBox;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            callApi();

        }

        private void callApi() {
            new DoGet(this, "videogallery").execute(WebserviceEndpoints.VIDEO_GALLERY);
        }

        public void handleVideoGalleryResponse(String response) {
            try {
                List<VideoEntry> list = new ArrayList<VideoEntry>();
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.optJSONArray("items");
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject data = array.optJSONObject(i);
                        JSONObject obj = data.optJSONObject("id");
                        JSONObject obj1 = data.optJSONObject("snippet");
                        String videoId = obj.optString("videoId");
                        String videoTitle = obj1.getString("title");
                        if (!videoId.equals("")) {
                            list.add(new VideoEntry(videoTitle, videoId));
                        }
                    }
                    VIDEO_LIST = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
                    adapter = new PageAdapter(getActivity(), VIDEO_LIST);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("", "handleResponse: ", e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
            videoBox = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.video_box);
        }

        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            String videoId = VIDEO_LIST.get(position).videoId;
            back = false;
            VideoFragment videoFragment = (VideoFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);
            videoFragment.setVideoId(videoId);
            if (videoBox.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
                if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                    videoBox.setTranslationY(videoBox.getHeight());
                }
                videoBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            if (videoBox.getTranslationY() > 0) {
                videoBox.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(ANIMATION_DURATION_MILLIS);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyView() {
            super.onDestroyView();

            VideoFragment f = (VideoFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment_container);
            if (f != null)
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.releaseLoaders();
        }

        public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
            if (adapter != null)
                adapter.setLabelVisibility(visible);
        }
    }

    private static final class PageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private final List<VideoEntry> entries;
        private final List<View> entryViews;
        private final Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap;
        private final LayoutInflater inflater;
        private final ThumbnailListener thumbnailListener;

        private boolean labelsVisible;

        public PageAdapter(Context context, List<VideoEntry> entries) {
            this.entries = entries;

            entryViews = new ArrayList<View>();
            thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            thumbnailListener = new ThumbnailListener();

            labelsVisible = true;
        }

        public void releaseLoaders() {
            for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
                loader.release();
            }
        }

        public void setLabelVisibility(boolean visible) {
            labelsVisible = visible;
            for (View view : entryViews) {
                view.findViewById(R.id.text).setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return entries.size();
        }

        @Override
        public VideoEntry getItem(int position) {
            return entries.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = convertView;
            VideoEntry entry = entries.get(position);

            // There are three cases here
            if (view == null) {
                // 1) The view has not yet been created - we need to initialize the YouTubeThumbnailView.
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.video_list_item, parent, false);
                YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
                thumbnail.initialize("AIzaSyB8BPeIbu5T1-flG4tpEdrHDPI3Rk2VTDY", thumbnailListener);
            } else {
                YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) view.findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
                YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(thumbnail);
                if (loader == null) {
                    // 2) The view is already created, and is currently being initialized. We store the
                    //    current videoId in the tag.
                    thumbnail.setTag(entry.videoId);
                } else {
                    // 3) The view is already created and already initialized. Simply set the right videoId
                    //    on the loader.
                    thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
                    loader.setVideo(entry.videoId);
                }
            }
            TextView label = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text));
            label.setText(entry.text);
            label.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
            return view;
        }

        private final class ThumbnailListener implements
                YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener,
                YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(
                    YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader) {
                loader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(this);
                thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.put(view, loader);
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
                String videoId = (String) view.getTag();
                loader.setVideo(videoId);
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(
                    YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeInitializationResult loader) {
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView view, String videoId) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView view, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_thumbnail);
            }
        }

    }

    public static final class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment
            implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

        private YouTubePlayer player;
        private String videoId;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            initialize("AIzaSyB8BPeIbu5T1-flG4tpEdrHDPI3Rk2VTDY", this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (player != null) {
                player.release();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }

        public void setVideoId(String videoId) {
            if (videoId != null && !videoId.equals(this.videoId)) {
                this.videoId = videoId;
                if (player != null) {
                    player.cueVideo(videoId);
                }
            }
        }

        public void pause() {
            if (player != null) {
                player.pause();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean restored) {
            this.player = player;
            player.addFullscreenControlFlag(YouTubePlayer.FULLSCREEN_FLAG_CUSTOM_LAYOUT);
            player.setOnFullscreenListener(onFullscreenListener);
            if (!restored && videoId != null) {
                player.cueVideo(videoId);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
            this.player = null;
        }

    }

    private static final class VideoEntry {
        private final String text;
        private final String videoId;

        public VideoEntry(String text, String videoId) {
            this.text = text;
            this.videoId = videoId;
        }
    }

    private int dpToPx(int dp) {
        return (int) (dp * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
    }

    private static void setLayoutSize(View view, int width, int height) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }

    private static void setLayoutSizeAndGravity(View view, int width, int height, int gravity) {
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = width;
        params.height = height;
        params.gravity = gravity;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

This is my fragment

The layout file is

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list_fragment"
        class="com.mycristoparish.Fragments.VideoGallery$VideoListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/video_box"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/close_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:src="@android:drawable/btn_dialog" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/video_fragment_container"
            class="com.mycristoparish.Fragments.VideoGallery$VideoFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</merge>
```

When I try to play the video in full-screen mode I get the following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #42: Duplicate id 0x7f0d0117, tag null, or parent id 0x7f0d0115 with another fragment for com.mycristoparish.Fragments.VideoGallery$VideoFragment
```

Please guide me how can I move further.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are inflating a layout with a fragment inside a fragment.You cannot do it and so you get the error.However you can dynamically add them.

[More details](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

> Note: You cannot inflate a layout into a fragment when that layout includes a . Nested fragments are only supported when added to a fragment dynamically.

Comment: the same example works fine if i try it with activity instead of fragment

Comment: Thats what i am saying , you cant do it in a fragment.You can do it in an Activity.